# How to check if time passed (timer)

Tags: javascript, html

I have code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get the Value of Text Input Field in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
    
    <script>
        function getInputValue(){
            // Selecting the input element and get its value 
           // var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
          var d = new Date();
          var n = d.getTime();
          var number = (document.getElementById("myInput").value);
          number=parseInt(number);
          var inputVal= number+n;
            
            alert(inputVal);
        }
       
        
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code I'm checking current time in milliseconds and in the form I write time in ms and sum current time with time in form and for example I want to add to current time 6000 ms and before this 6000 ms pass I want to pass for example to website information "ON" and after that "OFF". Should i use here loop to check if this time passed or I can do it other way ?

Comment: No, you should go look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if something is not clear (*I just really do not know what might be complicated here*)

Except for `+val`, this is instead of [`parseInt(val)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Except2 for `| 0`, this is instead of [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
$('#info').hide();
const getInputValue = ()=>{
    const val = $('#myInput').val();
    $('#info').fadeIn();
    console.log(`info here for ~${(+val / 1000) | 0} sec`);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $('#info').fadeOut();
    }, +val);
};
```

```css
*{padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" value="2000" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput" />
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Show Info</button>
<div id="info">Website information "ON"</div>
```

JQuery is not needed here

Answer (score 0):

using `requestAnimationFrame` API to make a recursion

[codepen demo timer](https://codepen.io/claviering/pen/poPBBYE?editors=0010)